# SQLITE Count job signup based on event id

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, count

I'm having trouble with a count query, I've been stuck on this for hours now...

So I have 3 tables:

job - id,name

event - id, name, date

signup - id, event_id, name, job_id

I want to count how many signups there are for each job in each event even the ones that are null, I do not need to filter events because there won't be many and I only have 15 jobs.

I want something like this:

```
event_id - job - count

1 - carpenter - 10
1 - miner - 0
1 - farmer - 3
2 - carpenter - 3
2 - miner - 4
2 - farmer - 0
```

This is as far as I have come:

```
SELECT signup.event_id, job.name AS "job", COUNT(*) AS "cnt"
FROM job
LEFT OUTER JOIN signup ON job.id = signup.job_id
GROUP BY job.name, signup.event_id
ORDER BY signup.event_id
```

that returns something like this:

```
event_id - job - count

NULL - farmer - 0
NULL - miner - 0
1 - carpenter - 10
1 - farmer - 3
2 - carpenter - 3
2 - miner - 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to get the rows and then `left join`/`group by` for the aggregation:

```
SELECT e.event_id, j.name AS job, COUNT(s.id) AS cnt
FROM event e CROSS JOIN
     job j LEFT OUTER JOIN
     signup s
     ON j.id = s.job_id AND e.id = s.event_id
GROUP BY e.event_id, j.name
ORDER BY e.event_id, j.name;
```